# fill a aspx combobox with a list of countries in swedish?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, devexpress, countries

can anyone tell me how to fill a aspxcombobox with a list of countries in swedish?

I have manage to do this with an english list of countries.

my code:

```
public static List<string> getCountryList()
{
    List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        if (culture.LCID != 127 && (culture.CultureTypes & CultureTypes.NeutralCultures) != CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
        {
            RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
            if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
            {
                cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);
            }
        }
    }
    cultureList.Sort();
    return cultureList;
}
```

In the config file I have set the following line:

```
<globalization uiCulture="sv" culture="sv-SE" />
```

thank you.

Comment: Note that i've added devexpress tag since i assume that `aspxcombobox` is [this control](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBoxtopic).

Answer (score 0):

**From:**[ASPxComboBox - How to localize individual item text](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q335287)

> ASPxComboBox does not allow one to localize Item's Text declaratively.
>   It is recommended to implement the localization procedure as you
>   already do it (or implement the localization at the datasource level,
>   for example, by introducing some service column that contains
>   translated text entries).

To localize combobox items that are created declaratively, or at runtime, you can use ASP.NET localization: [Resources and Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx). Localized strings can be gotten from resources.

References:
[ASPxComboBox as a "google" type search box](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q333082)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RegionInfo's [NativeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.nativename.aspx) property.  In this case, the editor will be filled using Swedish names of regions.